# Get SPUser information

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, spuser

I am trying to get a user's information off of SharePoint.  I can see the user's information through the UI when I click their name.  I can add them to groups and sites freely.  But no matter what I try, I cannot get the user's information through code.

Below is a portion of my code that cannot find the specific user.  I can find any other user.

```
SPUser userInGroup=...; //This is the user
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext context = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager profileManager = new Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager(context);
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(userInGroup.LoginName);
foreach (var property in profile.Properties)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("{0}", property.DisplayName, property.Name, profile[property.Name].Value);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    Console.Write("[{1}]", property.DisplayName, property.Name, profile[property.Name].Value);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write(":\t");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("{2}", property.DisplayName, property.Name, profile[property.Name].Value);
}
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
Console.WriteLine("----\t----\t----\t----\t----");
Console.ResetColor();
```

Am I pulling from AD or SP.  It looks like I am pulling from SP, but if I go into User Profile Service Application in Central Admin and search for the user, I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve User Profile information in SharePoint 2010 you should have User Profile Service application configured and activated. Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager dll need to reference needed.

SharePoint 2010 object model code to retrieve the data:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Site URL"))
{

SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);

UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(context);

UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile("Domail\\UserName");

String WorkEmail=profile[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].Value.ToString();

String FirstName = profile[PropertyConstants.FirstName].Value.ToString();

String LastName = profile[PropertyConstants.LastName].Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: If that is all I need, then how come the accounts I want can't be found?

Comment: did you try my code and is that work?

Comment: Your code is the same as my code.  Difference is you explicitly pull three properties whereas I pull every property.